# Ubuntu 12.10 DisplayLink Adapter No Green Screen

Tags: 12.10, gnome, xorg, displaylink

I initially wanted to get this working on 13.04, but have since given up.  If I get it working on 12.10, I may decide to upgrade, but that's irrelevant until such a time.

Unlike many reported cases of the combination of Ubuntu and the adapter not working, mine does not display anything on the monitor, least of all green. After a few days of frustrating searching, and failed attempts to build `xserver-xorg-video-displaylink` after discovering it isn't available from the repository anymore, I stumbled across [bug 812594](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-displaylink/+bug/812594) on launchpad for xserver-xorg-video-displaylink.

While the title was not encouraging, I looked through the comments anyway, and discovered Damiön's comment regarding Canonical Paid support.  The included README was highly illuminating, and decided to look at the `ATTR{name}` entry from `udevadm info --attribute-walk --path=$(udevadm info --query=path --name=/dev/fb1)`.  Surprisingly, it returned "udldrmfb," not an identifier I'd found before.  A quick search came up with a number of bugs concerning EDID extension blocks, which matched with my vague understanding from the `read-edid` package output.

That's about as far as I've gotten, and I'm rather stumped.  How can I get this adapter working?

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, the adapter will not be recognized by the driver unless you plug in the adapter after initial startup.  For me, that means plugging it in at the logon screen.